# grading a students test based on user input answers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, user-input

I have to

- Declare/Initialize an array to hold the correct answers to a 12 question multiple choice quiz whose
  answers are: 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', ‘B’, ‘A’
- Read in the answers for a single student into another array using a for loop
- ‘Grade’ the quiz and display the following:

  - Student Name
  - Quiz Score as a percentage to 1 decimal (ex: 7 out of 12 would display 58.3%)

and then

- First, at the top of your program, ask the user how many students there are in the class
- Loop through and input each student’s answers, ‘grade’ quiz, and display the result for each student
- After all students have been processed, display the values of the high and low scores and the average quiz score as a percentage (1 decimal)

program should end up looking like:

```
How many students are in the class? 2
Enter name for Student 1: Bob
Enter quiz score answers: <allow user to input 12 answers>
Bob
66.7%
Enter name for Student 2: Fred
Enter quiz score answers: <allow user to input 12 answers>
Fred
91.7%
The high score is 11 and the low score is 8
Average is: 79.2%
```

I have this array set up but I really don't know how to implement it using the for loops.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab4 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;

    char [] answerKey= { 'B' , 'D' , 'A' , 'A' , 'C' , 'A' , 'B' , 'A' , 'C' , 'D' , 'B' , 'A' };
    char [] userAnswers = new char[answerKey.length];



}
}
```

Thanks for the help so far guys,
I've worked on it a bit more but its giving me an error after entering the answers
this is what i have

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Lab4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    int students;
    int correctAnswers=0;

    char [] answerKey= { 'B' , 'D' , 'A' , 'A' , 'C' , 'A' , 'B' , 'A' , 'C' , 'D' , 'B' , 'A' };
    char [] userAnswers = new char[answerKey.length];

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");

    System.out.print("how many students are in your class?");
    input = s.nextLine();
    students=Integer.parseInt(input);

    String [] name = new String[students];

    int j=1;
    while(students>=j)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter name of student" + j + ": ");
        name[j] = s.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter quiz score answers");
            userAnswers[answerKey.length] = s.next().charAt(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < userAnswers.length; ++i)
        {
            if(userAnswers[i]==answerKey[i]);
            correctAnswers++;
        }

        System.out.print((df.format(correctAnswers/answerKey.length)) + "%");
    j++;

    }
    }
}
```

> The error message is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
>       at Lab4.main(Lab4.java:29)

I'm not sure what it means or how to fix it.

Comment: Beyond what was given to you in your assignment, what have you done?

Comment: the code at the bottom is what i have done, I know i need to put in for loops and reference back the arrays but I can't figure out how to do that. I was unable to make it to the class period where he talked about the bulk of the array usage so i'm pretty lost

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a way to make people write code for you.  It is a way to ask specific questions about the language that can only be explained by experienced programmers.  This is basic java we are talking about here, not anything complicated.

Comment: i'm not asking for someone to write the code for me but just to give me a basis on what i need to be doing next to get the right output. i just included all that was required of me just so that I could include enough information as possible. i've spent the last hour trying to look things up and I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: You can loop through every answer, and therefore ask for an associated answer by looping over each element in the array: `for (int i = 0; i < userAnswers.length; ++i) { /* current right answer is answerKey[i]; you need to fill in userAnswers appropriately */ }`

Comment: Thank you very much this actually clears up a lot.

Comment: @flafla2 I think this question is acceptable. He is asking for troubleshooting on a specific issue and guidance on how to approach the problem. It's not the best question, but I'm not sure that it merits these downvotes.

Comment: @flafla2 Perhaps point out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to a brand new user rather than bash them on the head with a big stick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jump to a quick tutorial on arrays -> http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/Arrays.cfm#.US09R-sjqy0

As stated in comments, we aren't going to write code for you, but I'll try to provide some helpful pointers:

Your going to want to prompt the user for how many students are in the class, this should have been taught in your class. Accept that input and store it in a variable.

Create a `while` loop to accept the data for each student. The loop should only run as many times as the user stated there were students.

In the loop accept all your student data, answers, names, etc.

After gathering all the data, you'll need to compare the students answer with the key. You can do this using a `for` loop or a `while` loop. I would recommend a for loop, create some kind of counter to keep up with how many answer were correct or incorrect, your choice then do the math after the loop to get your percentage.

Print the results and restart the loop.

Java Documentation on Arrays: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html

Some quick Array specific pointers:

Access an array:

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}; //creates array
System.out.println( array[0] ); //prints out "a"
System.out.println( array.length ); //prints out "4", the number of elements in the array
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks this actually does help a lot, I'm going to see if i cant make any progress, for storing the input would it just be userAnswers = s.nextLine(); or does it need to be formatted different because its an array and a char?

Comment: `System.out.println("Enter quiz score answers");
   userAnswers[answerKey.length] = s.next().charAt(0);`   is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: @JosephMindrup , I just got back online. You'll need to run another for loop to accept all the answers. Right now your only getting the next letter entered so that's only one letter when you need multiple letters. You can create a for loop to loop answerKey.length times and get another answer character, or you could ask the user to input their answers separated by commas ie: a,b,a,b,a,c,a,d then read that to a string var `String tempAnswers = s.nextLine();` then do `userAnswers = tempAnswers.split(",");`

Comment: This will effectively take one line input with all the answers and then split it based on commas into an array that you can use. It appears the mods have locked this thread, if you need more assistance I would recommend starting another question asking for specific help on a certain problem showing your code sample. I'll try to check this question again tomorrow to see if you're still stuck. best of luck!