# Grading a student's test based on input answers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, user-input

I had asked questions about this program earlier today and was able to get most of what I needed to done but it seems that people aren't looking at it anymore 
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100873/grading-a-students-test-based-on-user-input-answers) the link to it.

Here is what I have now:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Lab4 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    int students;
    int correctAnswers=0;

    char [] answerKey= { 'B' , 'D' , 'A' , 'A' , 'C' , 'A' , 'B' , 'A' , 'C' , 'D' , 'B' , 'A' };
    char [] userAnswers = new char[answerKey.length];

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");

    System.out.print("how many students are in your class?");
    input = s.nextLine();
    students=Integer.parseInt(input);

    String [] name = new String[students];

    int j=1;
    while(students>=j)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter name of student" + j + ": ");
        name[j] = s.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter quiz score answers");
        userAnswers[answerKey.length] = s.next().charAt(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < userAnswers.length; ++i)
        {
            if(userAnswers[i]==answerKey[i]);
            correctAnswers++;
        }

        System.out.print((df.format(correctAnswers/answerKey.length)) + "%");
    j++;

    }

}

    }
```

But I keep getting this error after I enter in the user's answers:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   12    at Lab4.main(Lab4.java:29)

I'm not sure what it means or how to fix it.

Comment: It means you're trying to read past the end of an array.

Comment: It means that you're trying to access an array in line 29 at the index 12, but your array is smaller than 13 elements.

Comment: It would be better if people who down vote a new user would explain why or at least point out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means your array index may exceed the number of elements in the array. From your code, it seems you exhibited an [Off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Note that Java arrays are zero based i.e array indexes starts with 0 and ends with `array.length - 1`.

(Note: untested code, and I haven't used `Scanner` for months...)

Change

```
int j=1;
while(students>=j)
```

to

```
int j = 0;
while (students > j)
```

And, as for this line

```
userAnswers[answerKey.length] = s.next().charAt(0);
```

It is a logical error. Not just it is writing out of bounds as per @Creakazoid answer, even if it is fixed, you will be writing all the answers to the last element of the array, and that means you will have all student answers as the last character the user input.

<s>This should be</s>

```
for (int i = 0; i < answerKey.length; ++i) {
    userAnswers[i] = s.next().charAt(0);
}
```

**EDIT:** It looks like you need read a line of input full of answers. So, read the entire line then break the line into characters. (untested)

```
String line = s.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < answerKey.length; ++i) {
    userAnswers[i] = line.charAt(i);
}
```

Furthermore,

```
if(userAnswers[i]==answerKey[i]);
```

Noticed the semi-colon at the end of line? You are writing an empty statement (consisting of a semi-colon) and `correctAnswers++;` will run no matter this condition is true or not

change it to

```
if (userAnswers[i] == answerKey[i])
```

You may need to change

```
System.out.print("Enter name of student" + j + ": ");
```

to

```
System.out.print("Enter name of student" + (j + 1) + ": ");
```

such that the output is not affected, though

---

In fact, your while loop can be replaced by a for loop - it is easier to read:

```
for (int j = 0; j < students; ++j) {
    // .. your code
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't completely understand for the for loop part are you suggesting i get rid of 'if(userAnswers[i]==answerKey[i]);
    correctAnswers++;' and replace it with the 'userAnswers[i] = s.next().charAt(0);'

Comment: sorry I'm having trouble figuring out to format it into a code box

Comment: Talking about that line, I just noticed another error - see my update.

Comment: putting the  userAnswers[i] = s.next().charAt(0) line before the if statement makes it so that after i enter in my scores nothing happens, no error codes, it just moves the cursor to the next line, am i not putting it in the right place?

Comment: userAnswers[i] = s.next().charAt(0) should be in a for loop, the if statement in another for loop. You can combine them, but I afraid you cannot do it the right way...

Comment: what do you mean I can't do it the right way? i ended up realizing what you meant and put it in its own for loop like you had said but the same thing is happening with the cursor.

Comment: nevermind, updated my answer. Try figure out yourself as I am at work and cannot help you at moment now.

Comment: Okay, thank you for all your help, I did not mean to bother you as much as I did.

Comment: This worked by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
userAnswers[answerKey.length] = s.next().charAt(0);
```

Array indices are zero-based, so the last addressable index would be `answerKey.length - 1`.

Comment: Thank you that fixed that error message but it gives me this when the program tries to rerun:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Lab4.main(Lab4.java:26)

Comment: is there something wrong with my while loop? that is kind of what it looks like its saying